# GDAL changes pixel resolution when transforming from HDF to netCDF

Tags: gdal, modis, netcdf, pixel, hdf

Using the MODIS product MCD18A1.061 (DSR 1km), tile h15v05-2001001, my goal is to extract the scientific datasets that are contained in an HDF to several netCDFs.

For this, I used the following gdal commands:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF -co 'FORMAT=NC4' HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:'{input}':MODISRAD:{sds} {output} 

gdalwarp -of netCDF -co 'FORMAT=NC4' {input} {output} -s_srs '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs '{shapeproj}' -srcnodata -1 -dstnodata -1 -overwrite

""gdalwarp -of netCDF -co "FORMAT=NC4" -cutline {shapefile} -csql "SELECT * FROM {shapefilename} WHERE {prop1}='{prop2}'" {input} {output} -srcnodata -1 -dstnodata -1 -overwrite""
```

According to the following images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

My problem seems to be in the first command (gdal_translate), since when converting from HDF to netCDF the resolution of the pixels decreases. I would like to know why the resolution is changed and how can I prevent this so that the netCDF file has the same resolution as the original (1km).

I tried to use the -tr option but got the same results, only the file size changed.

Comment: Have you tried using -te, as well as -tr, to set the corners of the netcdf to be the same as the  HDF:
`gdalwarp -te xmin xmax ymin ymax input output`
Check gdalinfo for the corners of the hdf.

Comment: But as you can see by the images, the pixel size changes when using gdal_translate and not gdalwarp.

This is part of gdalinfo of the original hdf file:
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center (  256.0,  256.0)

I tested gdal_translate with -a_ullr 0 0 512 512, but with no success.